# Unrecognized HTML <a> tag attribute: data-is-disabled

Tags: html, attributes

We had a web app developed by a third party. In one file, there are several instances of a HTML `<a>` tag with the attribute "data-is-disabled". I can find no reference to such an attribute. As such, it should be perfectly okay to delete it - correct?

More info: The app was developed using Laravel and is_disabled is a property of one of the data objects. Does Laravel do something with this tag?

Comment: "I can find no reference to such an attribute" — Where are you looking?

Comment: nope! ask the third-party developer if it is safe to remove.

Comment: General google search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a data attribute (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp). These are typically used to interact with JavaScript, so you cannot assume it's not used based on HTML only.

Besides: CSS may also target these links (e.g. a[data-is-disabled]

Comment: Thx. I did some more hunting around and there is a connection to some javascript. What is odd is that this construct only appears in one of the source files - despite almost identical behavior appearing in another. More mysteries...

Answer (score 2):

The data- prefix suggests that it is a user-defined attribute, created by the developer or the application. It's unlikely you'll find references to it anywhere online. If in doubt you should consult the ones who developed it, or leave the attribute alone. The error in your question title is likely the result of validating your HTML as HTML 4 or XHTML 1 (or older). Data attributes are new to HTML5 and the page doctype should reflect this: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

I'm not familiar with Laravel, but this attribute could well be used by it. Someone more familiar with the subject could comment further. Again, your best option is to consult your developer.